# Problems with lower thirds

Tags: video

I have a .mov file that has a black background but it’s not transparent. How do I change this file to make the black background transparent. Do I change the file in my editing software? If so how? I am using Adobe Premier Pro 2020.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your video file does not have an alpha channel (an extra channel of information in the video file that defines which bits of the video should be transparent):

1. Place the text .mov on a layer in your sequence
2. Select the clip
3. Go to the Effect Controls for that clip
4. Under the "opacity" heading, set the Blend Mode to Screen.

Anything black should now be transparent.

[image: screenshot]

If you think your file does have an alpha channel, check that the alpha is set correctly in Premiere:

1. Right click on your clip in your project
2. Choose Modify --> Interpret Footage
3. Make sure the Alpha settings are set as shown:

[image: screengrab]